# If "Angular doesn't offer filter/orderBy pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification", so what's the best alternative to?

Tags: angular, sorting, search, datatable, filtering

> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. filter and orderBy have often been abused in AngularJS apps, leading to complaints that Angular itself is slow. That charge is fair in the indirect sense that AngularJS prepared this performance trap by offering filter and orderBy in the first place.

Ref. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe

If I need to filter or order a datatable using a search input or clicking on some filter buttons, what's the best alternative to achieve that not using Pipes?

Comment: did you read the rest of the article you posted? the last two paragraphs say: 
"The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself". read the rest also, they point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did but I didn't really understand what they mean by "moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself". Is there any concrete example available?

Comment: I see. well, basically. instead of exposing an unordered list, you simply order it in your component and expose it as an ordered list. for example, if you get the list [1,4,2,3] and you want to display it in-order (low to high). you'd order it in your class instead of using a pipe to do so. you might do something like `ordered = unordered.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b;});` where`unordered = [1,4,2,3]` and the result would be `[1,2,3,4]` and then expose that and use it in your view. does that make sense ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the laziness of most of us developers. When we use template code we just want it to work without caring on the load. 
Suppose you had an object like this:

```
{
staff: [
    {name: 'Bill', title: 'dev', color: 'blue', id:9},
    {name: 'Luisa', title: 'dev', color: 'red', id:5},
    {name: 'Jim', title: 'dev', color: 'blue'}, id:1451],
company: {
    name: 'superCo'
}
}
```

And in your component you wanted to do a orderBy the `id`

So, you do: `ngFor="staff of data.staff | orderBy('id')`
What happens is it goes: ok, load ALL the data, go to this user, get the ID, compare it to all the others, ok got it, go to this user, get the id, compare it to the others, ok got it, go to the next user, get the id, compare it to the others, ok got it.. Ok I went through them all, here's an Array **That only exists in the template rendering**

Ok, build all the data models and components, for each user..

This is fine if it ran once... But it does it **ON EVERY DETECTION CYCLE**

Your entire object /sorting/filtering runs over and over, and if it's complex or you have a ton of data it can get wayyyy heavy. Your `sortBy('id')` would run 5-10 times a second.. Remember, your data is stored out of order, so it rebuilds the array 5-10 times a second in a change cycle.

Now, one way to help things is change your [DetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html) to `onPush()`

This would let you only run the cycle on the object when you specifically want to and not as often. This is good for **ANY** lists or sets of data. But it's still a big burden.

A better thing to do would be create your own sorting function `doSort()` or whatever. You run this when you click or whatever and then it changes the data array only once, triggers the `onPush()` detection and is ignored on subsequent passes..

Template code is also much harder to write tests for. When you shift the logic to the component code itself you can now do have `filterColors()` or whatever functions you want, and then run it against the data.

I know it isn't as fancy or cool as the `.orderBy('id').filterBy(selectedColor)` of the past, but it's significantly faster and more testable.

I rambled a bit, I hope that helps some..

Comment: Thanks Dennis. So, maybe the best alternative should be: 1. ngOnInit, load my JSON database; 2. Retrieve each property/value ordered in a static HTML table; 3. Create a local vanilla JS function in my component which will filter my local HTML table without reloading my JSON database each time, because it has been parsed; 4. Call this function when I type something in the Search Input with (keyup); 5. When the input value matches elements in my local HTML table, the other ones are hidden with a CSS `display:none;` property. Is that correct?

Comment: Close, you can still have the binding between your JSON and html table, just don't use a pipe filter to trigger the changes. So: 1.Load the data. 2. Bind it to your table to the JSON with `onPush()` detection. 3. Create your vanilla function to effect the JSON data object. Use a debounce and `MarkForCheck()`. 4. Call with the `keyup()` or `click()` 5. Your JSON will get changed only for the specific times you want it to vs 5-10 a cycle, and your HTML table will update with the `MarkForCheck()` call.

Comment: Interesting. By the way, could it be possible to have a concrete example? I'm not really sure how to achieve that.

Comment: See DeborahK's comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780843/angular-4-filter-search-custom-pipe on how to handle this inside your component.