# Angular 4 Filter Search Custom Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

So I am trying to build a custom pipe to do a search filter of multiple values in a ngFor loop. I have looked for a number of hours for a good working example, and most of them are based on previous builds and don't seem to work. So I was building the Pipe and using the console to give me the values. However, I cannot seem to get the input text to show up.

Here are the previous places I have looked to find working examples:

[Angular 4 Pipe Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769748/angular-4-pipe-filter)

http://jilles.me/ng-filter-in-angular2-pipes/

https://mytechnetknowhows.wordpress.com/2017/02/18/angular-2-pipes-passing-multiple-filters-to-pipes/

https://plnkr.co/edit/vRvnNUULmBpkbLUYk4uw?p=preview

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=filter+search+angular+2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgMhQpkjCFg

Here is the code that I currently have:

component.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ngModel="query" id="listSearch" #LockFilter>

      <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-12 col-sm-11" *ngFor="let lock of locked | LockFilter: query">
        <input type="checkbox" ngModel="lock.checked" (change)="openModal($event, lock)" class="check" id="{{lock.ID}}">
        <label for="{{lock.ID}}" class="check-label"></label>
        <h3 class="card-text name" ngModel="lock.name">{{lock.User}}</h3>
        <h3 class="card-text auth" ngModel="lock.auth">{{lock.AuthID}}</h3>
        <h3 class="card-text form" ngModel="lock.form">{{lock.FormName}}</h3>
        <h3 class="card-text win" ngModel="lock.win">{{lock.WinHandle}}</h3>
      </div>
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'LockFilter'
})

export class LockFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(locked: any, query: string): any {
    console.log(locked); //this shows in the console
    console.log(query); //this does not show anything in the console when typing
    if(!query) {
      return locked;
    }
    return locked.filter((lock) => {
      return lock.User.toLowerCase().match(query.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

I have imported the pipe into the module.

I am still a little newer to Angular 4 and am trying to figure out how to make this work. Anyways thanks for your help!

I guess I will need to be more specific. I already built out a filter search in JS that does not filter all of the options, which is what I am trying to do. Not just filter the User Name. I am filtering all 4 pieces of data. I chose a Pipe as this was what Angular suggests you do as they originally used them in AngularJS. I am just trying to essentially recreate the filter pipe we had in AngularJS that they removed for performance. All options I have found don't work, or are from previous builds of Angular.

If you need anything else from my code let me know.

Comment: Pipes that implement business logic other than output formatting are pretty much treated as antipatterns in Angular. Instead use functions to encapsulate the logic. Use it then in your binding: `let lock of filteredLocks ()`

Comment: I have an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199776/custom-pipe-to-sort-array-of-array

Comment: Yup! Deborah's answer is the way to go

Comment: @DeborahK I looked through your example in the link. I could not get that to work. I am trying to filter all options, not just the User Name. Why would you not use a Pipe as Angular suggests? I already built out the search filter using JS in the component.ts file, but it doesn't want to filter all options, which is why I chose to try out a Pipe.

Comment: I discuss that here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/ It includes info on why pipes are not recommended for sorting and filtering and how to do multiple values.

Comment: @T.Evans, as to your comment that Angular recommends pipe in this scenario is not really true ;) https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have to implement search functionality in my local and Here is Updated your code. please do this way.

Here is the code that I have to update.

**directory Structure**

```
app/
   _pipe/
        search/
          search.pipe.ts
          search.pipe.spec.ts
app/ 
   app.component.css
   app.component.html
   app.component.ts
   app.module.ts
   app.component.spec.ts
```

**command run for creating pipe**

```
ng g pipe search
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="query" id="listSearch">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-12 col-sm-11" *ngFor="let lock of locked | LockFilter: query">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="openModal($event, lock)" class="check" id="{{lock.ID}}">
    <label [for]="lock.ID" class="check-label"></label>
    <h3 class="card-text name">{{lock.User}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text auth">{{lock.AuthID}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text form">{{lock.FormName}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text win">{{lock.WinHandle}}</h3>
</div>
```

**component.js**

Note: In this file, i have to use dummy records for implementation and testing purpose.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    public search:any = '';
    locked: any[] = [];

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.locked = [
            {ID: 1, User: 'Agustin', AuthID: '68114', FormName: 'Fellman', WinHandle: 'Oak Way'},
            {ID: 2, User: 'Alden', AuthID: '98101', FormName: 'Raccoon Run', WinHandle: 'Newsome'},
            {ID: 3, User: 'Ramon', AuthID: '28586', FormName: 'Yorkshire Circle', WinHandle: 'Dennis'},
            {ID: 4, User: 'Elbert', AuthID: '91775', FormName: 'Lee', WinHandle: 'Middleville Road'},
        ]
    }
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchPipe } from './_pipe/search/search.pipe';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'LockFilter'
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

        if(!value)return null;
        if(!args)return value;

        args = args.toLowerCase();

        return value.filter(function(item){
            return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args);
        });
    }
}
```

I hope you are getting the pipe functionality and this will help you.

Comment: Thanks this is working perfect. I am able to filter all table columns.

Answer (score 4):

Simple filterPipe for Angular 2+

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class filterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], field:string, value: string): any[] {

    if(!items) return [];
    if(!value) return items;


    return items.filter( str => {
          return str[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
        });
   }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="listSearch" #search>
    <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-12 col-sm-11" *ngFor="let lock of locked | filter:'propName': search.value>
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="openModal($event, lock)" class="check" id="{{lock.ID}}">
    <label [for]="lock.ID" class="check-label"></label>
    <h3 class="card-text name">{{lock.User}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text auth">{{lock.AuthID}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text form">{{lock.FormName}}</h3>
    <h3 class="card-text win">{{lock.WinHandle}}</h3>
</div>
```

in HTML **PropName** is dummy text. In place of **PropName** use your any object property key.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code to filter specific column instead of all columns in table using custom filters

**filename.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">product name </th>
      <th scope="col">product price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let respObj of data | filter:searchText">
      <td>{{respObj.product_name}}</td>
      <td>{{respObj.product_price}}</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**filename.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-productlist',
  templateUrl: './productlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productlist.component.css']
})

export class ProductlistComponent implements OnInit  {

  searchText: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  data: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(url)
      .subscribe(
        resp => {
         this.data = resp;

        }
      )
  }
}
```

**filename.pipe.ts**
Create a class and implement it with **PipeTransform**, in that way we can write custom filter with **transform** method.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class PipeList implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args)
     return value;
    return value.filter(
      item => item.product_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am late to the party, I hope this helps somebody.
I have made a custom search pipe for Angular v6+(currently build in 16 as well).

- This pipe uses regex to search through the entire array of object passed through it.
- Since it is a regex, lowercase and uppercase are handled.
- It also returns a the count of the search which is updated dynamically.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aukk1b)

*You can also search against particular keys as well. Just change this line in the file mentioned below.*

**pure-search.pipe.ts**

```
const properties = Object.keys(item);
```

change this to

```
const properties = ['key1','key2','key3'] //mention the key names
```

> Make sure the object you're passing is single-level.This filter have worked smoothly with over 3000+ records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple explanation to create custom pipe..as available pipes does not support it.
I found this solution [here](http://musttoknow.com/create-custom-pipe-to-filter-data-in-datatable-ngfor-angular/)..Nicely explained it

Create pipe file advanced-filter.pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'advancedFilters'
})

export class AdvancedFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], ...args): any {
    if (array == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return array.filter(function(obj) {
      if (args[1]) {
        return obj.status === args[0];
      }
      return array;
    });

  }

}
```

Here, array – will be data array passed to your custom pipe
obj – will be the object of data by using that object you can add condition to filter data

We have added condition `obj.status === args[0]` so that data will get filter on status which is passed in .html file

Now, import and declare custom pipe in module.ts file of component:

```
import {AdvancedFilterPipe} from './basic-filter.pipe';

//Declare pipe

@NgModule({

    imports: [DataTableModule, HttpModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, ChartModule, RouterModule],

    declarations: [ DashboardComponent, AdvancedFilterPipe],

    exports: [ DashboardComponent ],

    providers: [{provide: HighchartsStatic}]

})
```

Use of created custom angular pipe in .html file

```
<table class="table table-bordered" [mfData]="data | advancedFilters: status" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">

                <thead>
                       <tr>
                             <th class="sortable-column" width="12%">
                                 <mfDefaultSorter by="inquiry_originator">Origin</mfDefaultSorter>
                             </th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="dashboard-grid">

                                <ng-container *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let counter = index;">

                                                <tr class="data-row {{ item.status }} grid-panel-class-{{ counter }}">                                      

                                                                <td class="align-center">{{ item.trn_date }}</td>

                                                                <td>{{ item.trn_ref }}</td>

                                                </tr>

                </tbody>

</table>


//If you are using *ngFor and want to use custom angular pipe then below is code

<li *ngFor="let num of (numbers | advancedFilters: status">
  {{ num | ordinal }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Java-like logic that I could think of which might not look very compact in terms of typescript, is as below:

```js
transform(value:IBook[], keyword:string) {       
        if(!keyword)
        return value;
        let filteredValues:any=[];      
        for(let i=0;i<value.length;i++){
            if(value[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())){
                filteredValues.push(value[i]);
            }
        }
        return filteredValues;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Available Books</h2>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bookName"/>
<ul class="books">
  <li *ngFor="let book of books | search:bookName"
    [class.selected]="book === selectedBook"
    (click)="onSelect(book)">
    <span class="badge">{{book.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can use the given function instead on the (input) event of your input box**

```
filterNames(event)
{
 this.names_list = this.names_list.filter(function(tag) {
 return tag.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
 });
}
```

Hope it helps..