# My search function doesnt work if we search again because the original array gets changed

Tags: angular

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (input)="search()">
```

We type something to search the first time it gets searched but again if we search then no records are found because the original array `records` is changed it would only consist of the records which are searched and not all the records how to deal with this problem.

I could create a second array to keep a copy of all the records and assign it to the original array in the else if condition but that would only work if we empty the search box and not if we search and type again without emptying the search box to the last character.

The records are shown in the table with ngfor. The search function is for that table

```
 searchTerm : any;
    records: any;  //array of objects

    search(){
 if(this.searchTerm !== ""){
     this.records = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
            return (res.name && res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()));
          });
} else if(this.searchTerm === "") {

}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your objects are in `this.records` and when you do search you assign the result again to the same variable `this.records`. The next time you search, you won't get it because the items does not exist in the array. Create another array for search results.

```
this.filteredRecords = this.records.filter((res: any)=>{
    return (res.name && res.name.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()));
});
```

And depends how you handle for different user cases. When you search you show `fiteredRecords` which contains results returned from your filter function, and in normal user case or `searchTerm` is empty:

```
else if(this.searchTerm === "") {
 this.filteredRecords = this.records
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular pipes are best solution for this scenario. Create a pipe for search it will filter and render filtered array in DOM but will not update your original array

[Angular Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780843/angular-4-filter-search-custom-pipe)

Comment: Angular Pipe for filter is not suggested, and was removed because of performance.

Comment: That performance issue is only for impure pipe right? if we are write pure pipe still performance problem? @MaihanNijat