# Angular: Failing to implement a search pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, full-text-search, angular-pipe

I was following the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47738717/12360035 and I tried to implement the code in my own solution, but it seems to fail. In my configuration there's a list of users generated and on top of that field there's a search bar used for searching users. Please see code for more information.
My search.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(!value)return null;
    if(!args)return value;

    args = args.toLowerCase();

    return value.filter(function(item){
        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args);
    });
}

}
```

users.component.html:

```
...
<div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="list-header">Element overview</p>

    <div class="form-group"><!--
      <label for="filter" class="lb-sm">Filter</label> -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="filter" placeholder="Filter" id="filter" [(ngModel)]="query">
    </div>

   <select name="userSelect" size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (change)="clickItem($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let user of users | search: query" value="{{user.firstname}}">
        {{user?.lastname}}, {{user?.firstname}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
...
```

My users.component.ts:

```
...
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  public search:any = '';
...
```

I get the error `Identifier 'query' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member` two times - at ngModel and in the ngFor pipe.
Also the searchable items are last names and first names so they start with a capital letter.

** UPDATE **
My JSON received from my BackEnd is the following:

```
[{"_id":"5df0f0dbb97cfc2f3c4b6381","firstname":"Chad","lastname":"Johnson","password":"$2b$10$Dk09I8Qtgb/x76kqD/8are/4l/ir4Rp1vVS9DFp5T6lIGw0ldLu/O","eMail":"chad@johnson.com","active":true,"__v":0},{"_id":"5df8ba0f99a34e2070aad054","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","password":"$2b$10$Szcw9PZfoYA.lIA843.wt.HE99vQhoWdnMdFmlWUXFgcsdZ8sEvri","eMail":"john@smith.com","active":true,"__v":0},{"_id":"5e15da927932c92e448c3574","firstname":"Maret","lastname":"Smith","password":"$2b$10$0cd7qTf0k9NNICfiVF1ddu/w0XftGU2EkYMXZlIuEj06hd8SU1qle","eMail":"maret@smith.com","active":true,"__v":0}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add **users** json/data/array ?. what does it contain

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxdegb) Stackblitz of your code...seems to be working fine...

Comment: Hey!, It looks like everything is right. as @Viqas said. I don't see any error in console. See this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vlpjjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. If still there is a problem can you reproduce it in stackblitz

Comment: @SameerKhan it seems that the code is working now, but VSCode still appears to throw the bloody `Identifier 'query' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member` error. It's a bug then?

Comment: it also makes my pipeline test fail. How do I fix it?